# Is RubyAMF production ready?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

Am considering using it for a project. It keeps getting recommended to me. I am wondering if anyone has had any success and can comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used RubyAMF in production before and it worked great but I abandoned it for [webORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-rails/overview.html) for rails because RubyAMF has not been supported or updated since 2008. You are doing the right thing by choosing AMF as your transfer protocol. Take a look at the performance gains on James Ward's blog it is substantial.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. I am looking into webORB now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the website](http://code.google.com/p/rubyamf/) it is production ready. I have never used it, I cannot comment.

It cites [JukeFly](http://jukefly.com) as a site that uses RubyAMF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to this now and to me I find the opposite of joker's answer to be true, [webORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-rails/release-history.html) (2006) is  dated and all but dead, and [rubyAMF](http://code.google.com/p/rubyamf/updates/list) seems to have much recent activity.  That said the most promising framework for rails/flex I have found is [RestfulX](http://restfulx.github.com/).